# Visual Studio Git pull error

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, git-bash

I get this error more often than not

> An error occurred. Detailed message: x conflicts prevent checkout

If I check in the "Changes", **I got no changes and no untracked file.**

So to solve this, I pop up git bash, and do a git pull.
I get no error, no conflict, git bash just do it like it was nothing.

Is this a bug in visual studio or is there a legitimate reason for that ?

(I'm on Visual Studio 2013 update 5)